# How can I view images smaller than the typical thumbnail size at their original size?

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, filemanager, thumbnails

I'm using 20.04 and I've noticed something that I really don't like about it: in Pictures, small images such as pixel art or icons are scaled-up as thumbnails. This is annoying because I remember using an older version of Ubuntu and it never had that issue: when the images were the same size as the thumbnails or smaller, they would render in the file manager at their actual size i.e. each pixel of the image would be shown as a pixel on screen. I don't like having small pictures scaled-up and all blurry: it looks awful, and I actually find that images used as icons (like the ones used with html files so that your page has a tiny image on its tab) are actually harder to see correctly when they are scaled-up because aside from blur, you're also looking at anti-aliasing at a scale where it doesn't work.

Is there a way of configuring nautilus so that the thumbnails can be made from larger images scaled-down, but small images are not scaled-up? Or alternatively, if there isn't a way of configuring nautilus to do this, is there another file manager where there is?